# Inconvenientes al asignar la configuración ice_root en h20

Tags: r

soy nuevo en la comunidad así como también usando h2o. Junto con mi equipo tenemos el inconveniente de que se llena el espacio en disco de /tmp a pesar de las configuraciones iniciales que asignamos. El SO del servidor es Red Hat.

El problema es el siguiente: Iniciamos una sesión `h2o` para ejecutar en paralelo un script **R**, pero cuando el `data.frame` es convertido a `h2o` el path `/tmp` crece hasta los 11 gbytes llegando a completar el 97% del espacio disponible. Intentamos configurar el parámetro `ice_root` pero el problema persiste.

```
#R Code
library(h2o)
# h2o.shutdown()
h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size = "60g", ice_root = "/home/Compartida_CD_GI/h2o_temp") 
#h2o.init(nthreads=-1)
TRAIN_H20 <- as.h2o(train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para transformar un `data.frame` a un objeto `h2o` cuando hacemos `as.h2o(train)`, lo que ocurre en primer lugar es que se exporta el `data.frame` completo a un archivo `.csv` para luego volverlo a importar como un objeto `h2o`. No sé bien por que, o como modificar este comportamiento, pero inicialmente `h2o` genera este `.csv` en la carpeta temporal del sistema (`/tmp` en Linux) y no hace caso al parámetro `ice_root`, seguramente por que esteúltimo path se use para otra información. Si el `data.frame` que tenés en memoria es enorme, vas a tener un problema si no dispones de espacio suficiente en la partición o carpeta temporal para alojar el archivo `.csv`.

Sin embargo hay un truco para evitar este problema y es el siguiente:

```
# Exportamos el dataframe directamente a una carpeta dónde si disponemos de espacio
ice_root = "/home/Compartida_CD_GI/h2o_temp"
train.csv <- tempfile(pattern = "train", tmpdir = ice_root, fileext = ".csv")
write.csv(train, file=train.csv)

library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size = "60g", ice_root = ice_root) 
# Importamos el dataframe desde el .csv
TRAIN_H20 <- h2o.importFile(train.csv, sep=",")
```

Básicamente hacemos lo que hace un `as.h2o()` generamos el `.csv` intermedio en una ubicación dónde disponemos de espacio y lo importamos luego. Por ahora esto te debería funcionar, si averiguo como configurar `h2o` para establecer el directorio temporal, edito la respuesta.

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. De esta manera también vemos una notable mejora en la performance aunque hay que tener cuidado con los tipos de datos inferidos del csv. Sobretodo con los factores. Saludos